# Monitoring AWS account spends

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am planning to build a dashboard to monitor the AWS expenditure, after googling I realized AWS has no API so that developers can hook and build an app to get the real time data. Is there any way to achieve it. Kindly help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, you are looking to monitor current AWS usage.

AWS provides optoins for same through "AWS programmatic billing access".
Once you enable it, AWS will upload csv file of your current usage every few hours to specified S3 bucket.

You need to write a program using your favourite programming language AWS S3 SDK to download and parse csv file and get real time data.

Newvem has a very good set of How to Guides available to work with AWS.
One of the guide 
http://www.newvem.com/how-to-set-up-programmatic-billing-access-for-your-aws-account/
talks about enabling programmatic billing access.

Also refer, http://www.newvem.com/how-to-track-costs-of-amazon-s3-cloud-objects/ , this talks about how to track cost of Amazon S3.

2) As mentioned by Mike, AWS also provides a way where you can get billing alert using Cloudwatch.

I hope above helps.
I recommend to refer Newvem how to guides to get more insight into AWS and its offerings.

Thanks,
Taral Shah

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to monitor actual spending data, @Taral is correct. AWS Programmatic Billing Access is the best tool for recording the data. However you don't actually have to write a dashboard tool to view it, there are a lot of them out there already.

The company I work for, [Cloudability](https://cloudability.com), automatically imports all of your AWS Detailed Billing data and let's you build out all of the AWS spending and usage reports you need without ever having to write any code or mess with any spreadsheets.

If you want to learn more, there's a good blog post at http://blog.cloudability.com/introducing-cloudabilitys-aws-cost-analytics-powered-by-aws-detailed-billing-files/

Answer (score 1):

For more information about Cloudwatch enabled monitroing refer
http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/ for more

To learn AWS faster way, refer how to guides of Newvem at
http://www.newvem.com/amazon-cloud-knowledge-center/how-to-guides/

Regards
Taral

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to enable detailed billing export to a S3 bucket (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/programaccess.html))

Then I wrote a simplistic server in Python (BSD licenced) that retrieves your detailed bill and breaks it down per service-type and usage type (see it on this GitHib [repo](https://github.com/oddskool/aws_billing)).

Thus you can check anytime what your costs are and which services cost you the most etc.

If you tag your EC2 instances, S3 buckets etc, they will also show up on a dedicated line.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch has an "estimated billing" API, which will get you most of the way there. See this ServerFault question for more detail: https://serverfault.com/questions/350971/how-can-i-monitor-daily-spending-on-aws

If you are looking for more detail you will need to download your CSV-formatted bill and parse it. But your question is too generic to provide any specifically useful answer. Even this will not be real time though.